# JWPlayer Javascript API for Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, jwplayer

I'm trying to get JWPlayer to return an alert when a few specific events happen from a flash player playing a local video. If you notice from the code below, onComplete, JWPlayer should return an alert, which can then be intercepted by onJsAlert from setWebChromeClient so I can do stuff with that information. Am I doing something wrong?

A possible reason, I can find here: [JWplayer Javascript interaction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493287/jwplayer-javascript-interaction-not-working) that it's being loaded locally. Is there any way I can bypass this issue? Would it be easier to load somehow by calling localhost? Is that even possible?

For those of you curious about why I generate an HTML file instead of just having one move from the assets - after scouring the Internet to figure out how to get a local flv player working correctly, the best option was to generate the HTML file with the custom information and write the file to the same directory as the FLV (hence the FileWriter function).

HTML code for JWPlayer embed:

```
private void createVideoHtml(File flvDirectory, File htmlFile, String videofilename)
{
    String htmlPre = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>";  
    String htmlCode =
            "<script type='text/javascript' src='"+ flvDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/jwplayer.js'></script>" +
            "<div id='mediaspace'>EZ Stream TV FLV Player</div>" +
            "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
            "jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({" +
            "'flashplayer': '"+ flvDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/player.swf', 'file': '" + videofilename + "', 'backcolor': 'FFFFFF', 'frontcolor': '000000', 'lightcolor': '000000'," +
            "'screencolor': '000000', 'volume': '100', 'autostart': 'true', 'mute': 'false', 'quality': 'false', 'controlbar': 'bottom', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'," +
            "events: { " +
            "onComplete: function() { alert('COMPLETED');}" +
            "}});" +
            "</script>";
    String htmlPost = "</body></html>";
    String finalHTML = htmlPre + htmlCode + htmlPost;

    try {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(htmlFile);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(f);
        p.print(finalHTML);
        p.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Code for webview and handling the Javscript alert:

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_player);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setInitialScale(60);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    getWindow().addFlags(128);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
        {  
            Log.d(TAG, message);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the code below for JWPlayer to Webview

```
private void createVideoHtml(File flvDirectory, File htmlFile, String videofilename)
{
    String htmlPre = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>";  
    String htmlCode =
        "<script type='text/javascript' src='"+ flvDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/jwplayer.js'></script>" +
        "<div id='mediaspace'>EZ Stream TV FLV Player</div>" +
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({" +
        "'flashplayer': '"+ flvDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/player.swf', 'file': '" + videofilename + "', 'backcolor': 'FFFFFF', 'frontcolor': '000000', 'lightcolor': '000000'," +
        "'screencolor': '000000', 'volume': '100', 'autostart': 'true', 'mute': 'false', 'quality': 'false', 'controlbar': 'bottom', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'," +
        "events: { " +
        "onComplete: function() { alert('COMPLETED');}" +
        "}});" +
        "</script>";
    String htmlPost = "</body></html>";
    String finalHTML = htmlPre + htmlCode + htmlPost;

    try {
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(htmlFile);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(f);
        p.print(finalHTML);
        p.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_player);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.setInitialScale(60);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
getWindow().addFlags(128);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
    @Override  
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
    {  
        Log.d(TAG, message);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Lando do I need to include any library for implementing JWPlayer to my android app?

Comment: If you want a native implementation I believe you will need to work with the [Android-SDK](http://www.jwplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/Android-SDK-Overview.pdf), otherwise using the default HTML+JS snippet should work as in the example above. I'm sure @ethan-jwplayer can give you a more complete answer :).

Comment: Also if you need a more detailed answer it is better to post a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of using the comments.

Comment: this works without adding any additional library locally. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while working with jwplayer, my conclusion was that the onComplete event isn't trustable in some cases.
Can you benchmark other events does work like the onTime event ?

Otherwise use the onIdle event and measure the time left ( getDuration - getPosition ) to get a custom onComplete event.

Comment: I've since abandoned this project. However, you can't do a getDuration - getPosition on a streaming video, if I'm correct. At least on what I was getting. It should be using some crazy javascript on the HTML side to get the flash video position. However, the onIdle solution seems like a good one, feel free to try it and see if that fixes it.